# What to do if filament spool won't fit in 3D printer

Tags: troubleshooting, filament, flashforge-adventurer-3, change-filament

My sample filament has just ran out. Luckilly, I've already bought more filament. The only problem I have is that the spool for the new filament won't fit inside my 3D printer. The filament itself works with my printer; it's just the spool that is the problem. Does anyone have any solutions for what to do if a filament spool won't fit in your 3D printer? For reference, I have the FlashForge Adventurer 3.

Comment: Keep your old empty rolls !  They're like screwtop jars, always useful for something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A spool does not need to be inside a printer. Or on. Or even next to.

My Ender 3 pulls his filament in from the rack above it, my TronXY X1 pulls it from about 80 cm to the left of it, where it hangs from a shelf.

When making a solution that pulls in filament from afar, it is necessary to make sure the path is unobstructed and works for the whole movement range of the printer without getting bent sharply, as that can snap or kink the filament.

In the case of the small printer you have, leave open or remove the door to the filament chamber and make sure to place the spool holder so it drags in the filament straight. There are even spool holders designed [specifically for this printer](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3163417).

There are many designs of spool holders out there, many of them free and with minimal assembly.

### RE-spooling

Some printers, especially ones that only take marked rolls, might need their spool cores re-filled. In that case, you need to take utmost care: re-filling a spool needs to be without any twist to the filament or you risk entangling, and you need to make sure to not kink or bend the filament in doing so, or risk breaking at those spots.

Due to the risks involved, this should be avoided whenever possible!

Comment: Had to look up the printer the OP mentioned. That one has a closed compartment in the side of the printer for the spool (max 0.5 kg spools). Your answer is still valid, but could perhaps be improved by mentioning that an outside spool can be used by leaving open the side cover (e.g. see https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3163417).

Comment: I have never seen a 0.5 kg spool.

Comment: @AndreKR, they're common for specialty filaments, but I've never seen one for ordinary PLA.

Comment: How about winding some filament onto the empty spool?

Comment: @Frog that's risking mis-winding and entanglement.

Comment: @Trish agreed, should be done properly or not at all

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am now using a broom placed on a box as a temporary rack for my 3D printer. I am also planning to 3D print  the extension piece for my printer's spool holder.